# Há uma forma de personalizar o function alert igual ao input required?

Tags: javascript, css, alert, tooltip, settimeout

Minha pergunta é um tanto específica, mas eu gostaria de saber se existe uma possibilidade de criar uma mensagem de `alert` com o padrão do input `required`?

A situação é a seguinte: tenho uma div linkada que irá encaminhar para outra página de conteúdo, este conteúdo ainda não será disponibilizado, porém a div estará lá. Ao invés de abrir um `alert` padrão queria saber se há como personalizar a function `alert` para ser exibida de maneira simples como a do `required`.

> ATUALIZANDO A PERGUNTA COM `Tooltip`

Com o `tooltip` em **javascript** consegui criar um balãozinho de diálogo ao clicar na div, escrevendo *"Em breve"*.

Utilizando o tooltip com `trigger: "click"` gostaria que o balãozinho sumisse sozinho automaticamente após alguns segundos, como fazer?

Encontrei esse exemplo, mas não consigo aplicar no meu código → https://jsfiddle.net/13k7nv4q/

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.div_circulo_icon_image').tooltip({title: "Em breve", placement: "top", trigger: "click"});   
});
```

```css
.div_circulo{
    position: relative;
    margin: 50px;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    border: 0;
}

.div_circulo_icon{
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -100px;

    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px #555;

    -webkit-transform:scale(1);
    -moz-transform:scale(1); 
    -o-transform:scale(1); 
    transform:scale(1);

    -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: 0.3s ease;
}

.div_circulo_icon:hover{
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.05);
    -moz-transform:scale(1.05); 
    -o-transform:scale(1.05); 
    transform:scale(1.05);
}


.div_circulo_icon_image{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center center;
background-image: url('https://static.pexels.com/photos/259264/pexels-photo-259264.png')
}

/*====================*/

.sentense {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 60px 0;
    line-height: 1;
}


.sentense_spantitle {
 width: 100%;
 color: #d6b161;
    opacity: 0.8;
    display: block;
    font-size: 26px;
    font-weight: 500;
    letter-spacing: 0.3px;
}


.sentense_text {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 30px 0;
}

.sentense_text::before {
    background: #d6b161 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 70%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    height: 1px;
    width: 25%
}


.sentense_text__spantext{
    color: #000;
    opacity: 0.8;
    display: block;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 500;
    letter-spacing: 0.3px;
    line-height: 1.5px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="div_circulo">

  <div class="div_circulo_icon">
   <a href="http://google.com/" class="div_circulo_icon_image">
    <div class="div_circulo_icon_image"></div>
   </a>
  </div>

  <div class="sentense">
   <span class="sentense_spantitle">Tradidi</span>
  </div>

  <div class="sentense_text">
   <span class="sentense_text__spantext"> quod et accepi </span>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: vc deve estar procurando por modal jquery

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_modal&stacked=h

Comment: @MarcosBrinner então Marcos eu procurei se tinha alguma pergunta já feita por aí e encontrei sobre os modals, porém só encontrei estilos pop-ups como esse do w3s que você mandou. Pode ser ignorância minha, mas não encontrei nenhum padrão o dialog do `required` :/

Comment: Cara isso é praticamente um Tooltip... Quando o cara clica no elemento o Tooltip aparece é isso que vc precisa?

Comment: @hugocsl dei uma olhada rápida, não conhecia o Tooltip. Aparentemente é isso que eu quero, mas já adiantando outra pergunta hehe: tem como personalizá-lo?

Comment: Procura por plugins que faça isso, é a forma mais fácil.

Comment: Vc usa Bootstrap? Se não, usa jQuery?

Comment: @vulgogandini Sim vc pode fazer do jeito que quiser existem mil opções para isso, O que vc tem que pensar é Quando e Como vc vai querer mostrar esse Tooltip. Vc quer que ao clicar na div ele apareça e suma depois de alguns segundos? Vc quer que ele apareça sempre por enquanto ou só se algum campo estiver preenchido etc. Seria bom vc explicar um pouco melhor pra eu poder fazer um exemplo pratico pra vc. Se for algo simples só com CSS as vezes resolve.

Comment: @hugocsl eu vi as opções `CSS Tooltip` no w3s, mas trabalha em `hover`. Eu queria que exibisse o Tooltip quando clicasse na div e desaparecesse depois de alguns segundos.

Comment: @hugocsl eu adicionei o `tooltip` ao código. Porém o que não consegui fazer foi fazer com que o balão sumisse depois de alguns segundos. https://jsfiddle.net/c4wpuatf/

Comment: Não tem como alterar as propriedades visuais  da janela alert. Nem como implementar uma modificação no Stilo da caixa. Isso é detido exclusivamente pelo browser. Então se quiser isso vais ter que dar um fork em um open browser e fazer sua própria implementação.

Comment: @AtilaSilva na verdade eu estava atrás do `tooltip` só não o conhecia ainda (:

Comment: Cara agora vc tem que fazer um setTimeout para remover esse Tooltipe, eu até tentei mas como não sou bom de JS o máximo que consegui foi fazer ele funcionar corretamente no primeiro clique, mas para funcionar novamente tem que clicar 2x :/

Comment: Na verdade o que está procurando seria um popover como este não? https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_popover&stacked=h

Comment: @dvd atualizei a pergunta...

Comment: @Leandro atualizei a pergunta

Comment: @hugocsl então eu atualizei a pergunta e coloquei um exemplo que encontrei, mas não consegui aplicar ao meu código ;-;

Comment: Sem problemas parece que o @dvd já resolveu, ele é o cara do JS rss. tmj

Comment: @hugocsl obrigado pela atenção ლ(´ڡ`ლ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use o callback da ferramenta com `shown.bs.tooltip`. Após o tooltip ser exibido, você pode definir um tempo em milisegundos com `setTimeout` para que o mesmo se esconda:

```
$(document).on('shown.bs.tooltip', function(e){
   setTimeout(function () {
      $(e.target).tooltip('hide');
   }, 1000);
});
```

**Veja:**

> Adicionei `onclick="event.preventDefault()"` no link para anular a
>   ação de redirecionamento.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.div_circulo_icon_image').tooltip(
      {title: "Em breve", placement: "top", trigger: "click"}
    );
});

$(document).on('shown.bs.tooltip', function(e){
   setTimeout(function () {
      $(e.target).tooltip('hide');
   }, 1000); // 1 segundo
});
```

```css
.div_circulo{
    position: relative;
    margin: 50px;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    border: 0;
}

.div_circulo_icon{
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -100px;

    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px #555;

    -webkit-transform:scale(1);
    -moz-transform:scale(1); 
    -o-transform:scale(1); 
    transform:scale(1);

    -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: 0.3s ease;
}

.div_circulo_icon:hover{
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.05);
    -moz-transform:scale(1.05); 
    -o-transform:scale(1.05); 
    transform:scale(1.05);
}


.div_circulo_icon_image{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center center;
background-image: url('https://static.pexels.com/photos/259264/pexels-photo-259264.png')
}

/*====================*/

.sentense {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 60px 0;
    line-height: 1;
}


.sentense_spantitle {
 width: 100%;
 color: #d6b161;
    opacity: 0.8;
    display: block;
    font-size: 26px;
    font-weight: 500;
    letter-spacing: 0.3px;
}


.sentense_text {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 30px 0;
}

.sentense_text::before {
    background: #d6b161 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 70%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    height: 1px;
    width: 25%
}


.sentense_text__spantext{
    color: #000;
    opacity: 0.8;
    display: block;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 500;
    letter-spacing: 0.3px;
    line-height: 1.5px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="div_circulo">

  <div class="div_circulo_icon">
   <a href="http://google.com/" onclick="event.preventDefault()" class="div_circulo_icon_image">
    <div class="div_circulo_icon_image"></div>
   </a>
  </div>

  <div class="sentense">
   <span class="sentense_spantitle">Tradidi</span>
  </div>

  <div class="sentense_text">
   <span class="sentense_text__spantext"> quod et accepi </span>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Agora, notei que o método funciona melhor com Bootstrap 4:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.div_circulo_icon_image').tooltip(
      {title: "Em breve", placement: "top", trigger: "click"}
    );
});

$(document).on('shown.bs.tooltip', function(e){
   setTimeout(function () {
      $(e.target).tooltip('hide');
   }, 1000);
});
```

```css
.div_circulo{
    position: relative;
    margin: 50px;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    border: 0;
}

.div_circulo_icon{
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -100px;

    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px #555;

    -webkit-transform:scale(1);
    -moz-transform:scale(1); 
    -o-transform:scale(1); 
    transform:scale(1);

    -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: 0.3s ease;
}

.div_circulo_icon:hover{
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.05);
    -moz-transform:scale(1.05); 
    -o-transform:scale(1.05); 
    transform:scale(1.05);
}


.div_circulo_icon_image{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center center;
background-image: url('https://static.pexels.com/photos/259264/pexels-photo-259264.png')
}

/*====================*/

.sentense {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 60px 0;
    line-height: 1;
}


.sentense_spantitle {
 width: 100%;
 color: #d6b161;
    opacity: 0.8;
    display: block;
    font-size: 26px;
    font-weight: 500;
    letter-spacing: 0.3px;
}


.sentense_text {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 30px 0;
}

.sentense_text::before {
    background: #d6b161 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 70%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    height: 1px;
    width: 25%
}


.sentense_text__spantext{
    color: #000;
    opacity: 0.8;
    display: block;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 500;
    letter-spacing: 0.3px;
    line-height: 1.5px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="div_circulo">

  <div class="div_circulo_icon">
   <a href="http://google.com/" onclick="event.preventDefault()" class="div_circulo_icon_image">
    <div class="div_circulo_icon_image"></div>
   </a>
  </div>

  <div class="sentense">
   <span class="sentense_spantitle">Tradidi</span>
  </div>

  <div class="sentense_text">
   <span class="sentense_text__spantext"> quod et accepi </span>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: é exatamente isso que eu queria! Mas só uma observação... o @hugocsl reportou a mesma coisa ali nos comentários, na primeira vez ele funciona certinho já na segunda é preciso dar dois cliques. Até achei que fosse por causa do `hover`, mas não era...

Comment: ata, realmente com o Bootstrap não dá o bug do clique. Deus lhe pague!! (: